# flash as3 and adobe air -- save drawing file with the ability to undo/redo afterwards

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, air, save

I'm making an Adobe Air drawing app using Flash CS6. I would like to have a save option that lets you undo/redo drawing line strokes after you have saved and exited the program and opened it another time.

I have researched about BitmapData, Bitmap, Sprite, File, and FileStream, but nothing came to me as a way to save with the ability to undo/redo after.

By the way, I have already made functions for saving, opening, and reading the file. I just have no idea on what to put in the file being saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a class for each line that will hold the graphics object in it. On every stroke create an instance of that class and add it to an array. On save (let's imagine you save an XML file) you can make a node like `< canvas >` where you store all the sub-nodes with every line info.

On load read the XML file and recreate the array with your objects. The order of the XML node will be your depth/z-index/layer order and your history to undo/redo.

If you wish to take it further, let's say undo only the color change of a stroke, you will need to make a ActionHistory class that will point an action and object.

Hope that helps!